# How to run zap in command line for windows with form based authentication?

Tags: command, line, zap

Can anybody help on running zap in commmand line for windows ,especially login credentials when a part of the application is behind a login

Answer (score 1):

Not in a stackoverflow answer, no. The answer is too complicated.
For automation options see https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/
For authentication options see https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/